# Is my query getting cached?

Tags: railo, cfml

I'm used to Adobe ColdFusion and have been caching queries using `cachedafter` with a "simple" date:

```
<cfparam name="application.icons_last_changed" default="#now()#">
<cfquery name="get_icons" cachedafter="02/02/1978" datasource="#application.datasources.main#">
SELECT icon_id, icon_name
FROM REF_Icon
WHERE #application.icons_last_changed#=#application.icons_last_changed#
ORDER BY sort_order
</cfquery>
```

I transitioned my project from ColdFusion/MSSQL to Railo/PostgreSQL. Today, something in the Railo diagnostics caught my eye.

- I'm used to seeing "get_ref_icon (Datasource=Workstream, **Time=cached**, Records=39) in /path/qry_get_ref_icon.cfm"
- but in Railo I see "get_ref_icon (Datasource=Workstream, **Time=0.974 ms**, Records=39) in /pathqry_get_ref_icon.cfm".

Thinking that perhaps the simple data value ("02/02/1978") for `cachedafter` isn't supported by Railo, I tried setting the date with `createodbcdatetime('1978-02-02 16:37:00')`, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Of course, 0.974 ms is such a small time that perhaps the query is cached, and Railo just isn't as explicit as ColdFusion.

Is my query getting cached, or am I going about it the wrong way?

Comment: Does this happen all the time?

Comment: Yes--lots of data points for this when I compare ColdFusion diagnostics output to Railo diagnostics output.

Comment: And it's not a simple case of looking at the diagnostics for the first time the query was run?  Also, does Railo show the same de-bugging information that's avaialble on ColdFusion?

Comment: No, not the simple case (I hit refresh a couple of times). Railo's diagnostics output looks the same as CF...maybe a little extra, in fact.

Comment: I don't think its possible for a system to do a database query in 0.9ms if it wasn't cached.  I'd lean towards saying that Railo's debugging is just being more informative.  Have you tried taking out the cached statement and seeing if it goes up significantly?

Comment: Why are you using cachedafter instead of other caching methods? I mean, it should work, but I don't understand the point here?

Comment: Which version of Railo is this? I'm seeing time=0ms for cached queries in 4.0.3.004

Comment: @PeterBoughton: Railo 4.0.2.002 final. I cache query results that are used often, but rarely change. Sort of like CDN for queries, now that I think about it. Anyway, the query includes an application-scoped variable holding the date/time of when the data was last changed. This variable is set to equal itself in the `WHERE` clause (ie: `WHERE #application.icons_last_changed#=#application.icons_last_changed#`). It always evaluates as true, but a change in that date resets the query's cache.

Comment: I'm away from my usual machine @ the mo' (and for the next week), so don't have Railo etc available to test with. But the easiest way to test if you query is being cached is to run it, change the underlying data, then run it again. If you see the same result both runs, it's being cached. If you see the updates you made: not cached. I would expect that it's just Railo's debug output being vague. It might be an idea to ask this question on the Railo Google group, too: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/railo

Comment: Thanks @AdamCameron. I'll muster up some gumption, get off my lazy *&^ and do so (then report back here).

Comment: Chuckle. Was that an allusion to that article on my blog? ;-) I almost quoted that at someone today (on a different forum).

Comment: @AdamCameron: No, "gumption" was a coincidence, but I just read and enjoyed your post. A little pushback: StackOverflow is more than just a place for soliciting help. Its real power is as a knowledgebase.

Comment: In ACF at least you can see if its cached or not by dumping it or using the result attribute, does that not apply to railo?

Comment: Jeromy, what I meant was why that particular method - cachedafter - why not just do:

`<cfif RefreshCache OR NOT StructKeyExists(Application.Cache,'Icons')><cfquery name="Application.Cache.Icons">...</cfquery></cfif>`

Or equivalent. i.e. Why use a date-based cache when the date is never relevant?

Comment: @PeterBoughton: That technique wouldn't recognize a change in the query text, n'est pas? So updating `#application.icons_last_changed#` above wouldn't trigger a reset of the query cache...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, the query is not getting cached.**

I followed Busches's suggestion and reviewed the results from `<cfdump var="#get_icons#" />`:

```
Query
Template:/super/double/secret/path/qry_get_ref_icon.cfm 
Execution Time (ms):0.624 
Recordcount:39 
Cached:No                                     <--UH OH, SPAGHETTI-O's
Lazy:No 
SQL: 
SELECT icon_id, icon_name 
FROM REF_Icon 
WHERE active_ind=1 /*{ts '1978-02-02 16:37:00'}*/ 
AND {ts '2013-02-20 22:25:14'}={ts '2013-02-20 22:25:14'} 
ORDER BY sort_order
```

Because I'm a distrustful type, I also followed Adam Cameron's suggestion and changed some data then reran the query. Query results updated, so no caching.

---

I've reported the issue to the fine Railo folks: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO-2318

Comment: I also upgraded to Railo 4.0.3.005 final...still no caching.

Comment: There is code relating to cachedafter in the Railo source, so it appears to be supported and thus _should_ work; try doing `cachedwithin=1` to verify if that's the issue or if there's some other issue preventing caching from taking effect.

Comment: Ok, in that case it seems to be a bug - can you [log an issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO) for it.